# How to send WhatsApp message without user interaction using android accessibility service?

Tags: android, whatsapp

I am trying to develop a small app that can send WhatsApp messages without user interaction,
I know that this is the kind of problem that may a lot of people are trying to solve.

I am using accessibility services to do such things.

This is a sample of my code.
`Accessibility Service Class`

```
class WhatsappAccessibilityService : AccessibilityService() {
    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent) {
        if (rootInActiveWindow == null) {
            return
        }
        val rootInActiveWindow = AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.wrap(rootInActiveWindow)

        val messageNodeList = rootInActiveWindow.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.whatsapp:id/entry")
        if (messageNodeList == null || messageNodeList.isEmpty()) {
            return
        }

        val messageField = messageNodeList[0]
        if (messageField.text == null || messageField.text.length == 0 || !messageField.text.toString()
                .endsWith("mysuffix")
        ) {
            return
        }

        val sendMessageNodeInfoList = rootInActiveWindow.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.whatsapp:id/send")
        if (sendMessageNodeInfoList == null || sendMessageNodeInfoList.isEmpty()) {
            return
        }
        val sendMessageButton = sendMessageNodeInfoList[0]
        if (!sendMessageButton.isVisibleToUser) {
            return
        }

        sendMessageButton.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK)
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500)
            performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK)
            Thread.sleep(500)
        } catch (ignored: InterruptedException) {
        }
        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK)
    }

    override fun onInterrupt() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
```

And this is my `whatsapp_service.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowContentChanged"
    android:packageNames="com.whatsapp"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"/>
```

This is my `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.messagewithwhatsapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MessageWithWhatsapp">
        <service
            android:name=".WhatsappAccessibilityService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="My Accessibility Service" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/whatsapp_service"/>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And finally, this is how I implemented the send login.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.btnSend.setOnClickListener {
            if (!isAccessibilityOn(this@MainActivity, WhatsappAccessibilityService::class.java)) {
                val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS)
                this@MainActivity.startActivity(intent)
            } else {
                val smsNumber = binding.txfPhone.editText?.text.toString()
                val sendIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                sendIntent.type = "text/plain"
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "${binding.txtfMessage.editText?.text} mysuffix")
                sendIntent.putExtra("jid", "$smsNumber@s.whatsapp.net")
                sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp")
                startActivity(sendIntent)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun isAccessibilityOn(context: Context, clazz: Class<out AccessibilityService?>): Boolean {
        var accessibilityEnabled = 0
        val service: String = context.packageName + "/" + clazz.canonicalName
        try {
            accessibilityEnabled = Settings.Secure.getInt(
                context.applicationContext.contentResolver,
                Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED
            )
        } catch (ignored: Settings.SettingNotFoundException) {
        }
        val colonSplitter = SimpleStringSplitter(':')
        if (accessibilityEnabled == 1) {
            val settingValue: String = Settings.Secure.getString(
                context.applicationContext.contentResolver,
                Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES
            )
            colonSplitter.setString(settingValue)
            while (colonSplitter.hasNext()) {
                val accessibilityService = colonSplitter.next()
                if (accessibilityService.equals(service, ignoreCase = true)) {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

What happen are:

1. I press the send button in my app and firstly my app checks for `Accessibility Service`.
2. If the Accessibility service is off then my app will launch system settings to grand the Service.
3. But if the Accessibility service is on for my app service then it should open WhatsApp and start the service to allow clicking on the WhatsApp send button.
4. My service not working I tried to use the `Log` class but nothing show in the `run` for android studio.

Please anyone can help me and tell me how to do that.

Comment: Have you sorted out this issue?

Comment: I am looking for the same but for both WhatsApp and WhatsApp business but I don't know how to achieve in a single service. yes it is working in two different service.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are doing well.

Please try following code it will work

```
String uri = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+number+"&text="+message;
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
            sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(sendIntent);
```

your accessibility services code is ok.